# ¿Como hago un loop del coeficiente de gini en diferentes archivos?

Tags: r, bucles

Quiero hacer un loop que primero me lea todos los archivos que estan dentro de una carpeta en formato excel, y despues que haga dos columnas con la formula de gini, dentro de cada archivo, especificando las columnas que ocupare para esta formula de gini.

He intentado el siguiente codigo:

```
files <- list.files("/Downloads/ITER_07_2020_xlsx")
files

for(i in 1:length(files)) {
 print(gini_cel <- gini(VPH_CEL,w=TVIVPARHAB),
       gini_pc <- gini(VPH_PC,w=TVIVPARHAB) 
  )
}
```

Sin embargo, solo me lanza un dataframe con el ultimo con las operaciones hechas del ultimo archivo.

Comment: Para obtener ayuda de mejor manera deberías intentar generar un ejemplo mínimo (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
De lo que se entendí de tu problema, dentro del loop asignas el resultado a las misma variables `gini_cel` y `gini_pc `, por lo que cada iteración reemplazara los valores de la anterior. Es por esto que solo queda el valor de la ultima iteración. 
Para no perder los valores puedes crear una lista o un dataframe antes de iniciar el loop y añadir el resultado de cada iteración a la lista o al final del dataframe.

Comment: ¿De dónde sale la función `gini()`?

Comment: `list.files` acepta diversos argumentos (patrón, carpeta, etc), pero no el nombre de un archivo. Para hacer un bucle, lo que estás iterando es el valor de `i`, si `i` no está utilizado en ninguna parte del bucle, el resultado siempre será el mismo. Al menos sube un ejemplo de listado de archivos y la cabecera de alguno para ver como crear el bucle. También el paquete que contiene la función `gini`